Confirmation Wizard for Save Button in Odoo 15
I'm trying to create a wizard confirmation for the default save button in a tree view. I'm using odoo v15.
I tried to override the write method, but it doesn't work, and the changes are not saved. Here are my file
WizardModel wizard_confirm.py
from odoo import models, fields, api

class ConfirmSaveWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'confirm.save.wizard'
    _description = 'Confirmation Wizard for Save Action'

    message = fields.Text(string="Message", default="Do you want to save the changes?")

    def confirm_action(self):
        active_id = self.env.context.get('active_id')
        write_vals = self.env.context.get('write_vals')
        if active_id and write_vals:
            alumno = self.env['estudiantil.alumno'].browse(active_id)
            alumno.sudo().write(write_vals)
        return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}

Alumno Model estudiantil_alumno.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api
from odoo.exceptions import UserError

class Alumno(models.Model):
    _name = 'estudiantil.alumno'
    _description = 'Alumno'
    _rec_name = 'nombre'   
    
    
    cedula = fields.Char( string='Cédula',size=10, required=True, default="0000000000")    
    edad = fields.Integer(string='Edad',)        
    nombre = fields.Char(string='Nombres y apellidos',)    
    
    def write(self, vals):
        # Guardar valores a escribir en el contexto para el wizard
        context = dict(self.env.context, write_vals=vals)
        
        action = {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'name': 'Confirm Save',
            'res_model': 'confirm.save.wizard',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'target': 'new',
            'context': context,
        }
        return action

Alumno View estudiantil_alumno_view.xml
<odoo>
  <data>
    <!-- explicit list view definition -->

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="estudiantil_alumno_view_tree">
      <field name="name">Alumno</field>
      <field name="model">estudiantil.alumno</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree>
          <field name="cedula"/>
          <field name="nombre"/>
          <field name="edad"/>
         
        </tree>
      </field>
    </record>


    <record id="estudiantil_alumno_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">Alumno</field>
      <field name="model">estudiantil.alumno</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form >
          <sheet>
            <group >
              <group colspan="2">
                <field name="nombre"/>               
              </group>
              <group>
                <field name="cedula"/>                
              </group>             
              <group>
                <field name="edad"/>
              </group>
            </group>
          </sheet>
        </form>
      </field>
    </record>


    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="estudiantil_alumno_action">
      <field name="name">Alumno</field>
      <field name="res_model">estudiantil.alumno</field>
      <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem name="Alumno" id="estudiantil_alumno" parent="estudiantil_listado" action="estudiantil_alumno_action" sequence="1"/>
   
  </data>
</odoo>

This method works with a custom button, but not for the default save button.
